# Map Centered on Current Location with a Marker? React Native Expo

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, react-native-maps

I have a mapView, and I want to centre my map on the user's current location when the map screen is opened. By following the expo documentation, it should be achieved with Expo Location API. However, the documentation is unclear. I took part of the code from expo Location documentation. So, how should I integrate it in MapView in order to execute the getCurrentPositionAsync method and centre the map accordingly? Thanks for the help

```
import React, { useContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import MapView from "react-native-maps";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { Searchbar } from "react-native-paper";
import { View } from "react-native";

import * as Location from 'expo-location';

const Map = styled(MapView)`
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
`;

const SearchBarContainer= styled(View)`
padding: ${(props) => props.theme.space[3]};
position: absolute;
z-index: 999;
top: 20px;
width: 100%;
`;

export const MapScreen = ({navigation}) => {

  const [location, setLocation] = useState(null);
  const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      let { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
      if (status !== 'granted') {
        setErrorMsg('Permission to access location was denied');
        return;
      }

      let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
      setLocation(location);
    })();
  }, []);

  return (
    <> 
    <SearchBarContainer>
      <Searchbar placeholder="location"/>
    </SearchBarContainer>
    <Map showsUserLocation={true}>
      
    </Map>
    </>
  );};
```

Comment: Maybe the `initialRegion` prop of `react-native-maps` will do the trick for you. You can assign the user location that you have already retrieved, to that prop.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is missing the region / initialRegion prop in the Map component, that's where you'll tell it to be at the location. You may also want to use a Marker to point out the specific location. Lastly, you may want to consider naming the 'stated' location and the 'obtained' location different names for clarity (not sure if it affects the code as well).

```
    <MapView        
          region={{
              latitude: location.latitude,
              longitude: location.longitude,
              latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
              longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
            }}>
          <Marker coordinate={location}>
          </Marker>
       </MapView>
```